# Django slow query with a nullable Foreignkey

Tags: python, django

Imagine we have this two models

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    fetch_datetime = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    tracking = models.ForeignKey(Tracking, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)


class Tracking(models.Model):
    MANUAL = "Manual"
    AUTO = "Auto"
    UNMATCHED = "Unmatched"

    MATCHING_TYPES = [(MANUAL, "Matched by a human"), (AUTO, "Matched by a computer"), (UNMATCHED, "Not matched")]
    matching_status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=MATCHING_TYPES, default=UNMATCHED)
```

And we want to query like this

```
Offer.objects.filter(fetch_datetime__range=(now_minus_14days, now))
             .select_related('tracking')
             .filter(tracking__matching_status__iexact="manual")
             .annotate(
                 fetch_day=Cast("fetch_datetime", DateField())
             )
```

When the query is executed with the default index that django creates on the field Offer.tracking the query is so slow. On the other hand, when we get rid of this index, the query is fast. I'm so confused.

Anybody can give a solution? (I want to preserve the index)

Thank's in advance

Comment: What is your database backend?
Can you try to use QuerySet.explain() to see the execution plan?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#explain

Comment: The db backend is postgresql

Comment: ```Hash Join  (cost=3062.85..12832.30 rows=42 width=1314)
  Hash Cond: (offer.tracking_id = tracking.id)
  ->  Index Scan using idx_fetch_datetime on offer  (cost=0.43..9744.50 rows=9631 width=1059)
        Index Cond: ((fetch_datetime >= '2021-06-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (fetch_datetime <= '2021-06-17 15:12:28.906844'::timestamp without time zone))
  ->  Hash  (cost=3060.32..3060.32 rows=168 width=251)
        ->  Seq Scan on tracking  (cost=0.00..3060.32 rows=168 width=251)
              Filter: (upper((matching_status)::text) = 'MANUAL'::text)```

Comment: It doesn't look like an index on matching_status column is used.
Can you try using this filter instead?

`.filter(tracking__matching_status=Tracking.MANUAL)`

Comment: Amazing Micky. You are my hero. Thank's a lot!! Now it works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using iexact causes the generated query to perform a upper() function on the matching_status column.  This makes the database not use the index.

The solution was to change the filter to do an exact match so the query generated does not manipulate the matching_status column.  Since this column is using choices, it is best practice to use the defined choices in the filter.

```
.filter(tracking__matching_status=Tracking.MANUAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Offer.objects.filter(
                      fetch_datetime__range=(now_minus_14days, now), 
                      tracking__matching_status__iexact="manual").select_related('tracking')
                      .annotate(
                      fetch_day=Cast("fetch_datetime", DateField())
                     )
```